# Showing that f is Riemann integrable

Tags: real-analysis

$\newcommand{\sgn}{\operatorname{sgn}}$Let $\sgn:\mathbb R \rightarrow\mathbb R$ be the signum function

$$\left\{ \begin{array}{rcl}
         1& \mbox{when}
         & x>0 \\ 0  & \text{when} & x=0 \\
         -1 & \text{for} & x<0
                \end{array}\right.$$

let $f:[-1,1] \rightarrow\mathbb R$ be a countinuous function. Show that  $f$ is Riemann Stieltjes integrable with respect to sgn, and that

$$\int_{[-1,1]}f \, d\sgn = 2f(0).$$

I have the hint that says find for every $\varepsilon>0$ a piecewise continuous function majorizing and minorizing $f$ whose Riemann-Stieltjes integral is $\varepsilon$-close to $2f(0).$

I am having continuous function on a closed inteval $[-1,1],$ so $f$ is uniformaly continuous and hence by the theorem it is RSI. Also, $\sgn(x)$ is continuous and uniformly continuous since its derivative is bounded, and hence I conclude that $\int_{[-1,1]}f \,d \sgn$ is Riemann-integrable. But the problem I am getting stock on is showing that $$\int_{[-1,1]}f \, d \sgn=2f(0)$$

So I would appreaciate any help with that. Thank you.

Comment: Please replace *Reiman* or *Reimann* with *Riemann* and improve formatting.

Comment: The signum is **not** continuous on $[-1,1]$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Start writing the sum corresponding to the integral
$$
\sum_{i=0}^nf(x_*)\left(\alpha(x_{i+1})-\alpha(x_i)\right)
$$
with $\alpha(x)=\sgn(x)$ and $x_{i+1}\geq x_*\geq x_{i}$. The only value of this sum which contributes is the term including
$$
\alpha(x_{m+1})-\alpha(x_m)
$$
where 
$$
x_{m+1}>0>x_m
$$
which then has value $\alpha(x_{m+1})-\alpha(x_m)=2$. In the limit, $f(x_*)\to f(0)$, which is finite since $f$ is continuous on a compact domain. Such a term exists thanks to $\sgn(0)=0$.

Comment: Alright that makes sense . But could you please explain more how this integral= 2$f(0)$

Comment: In the end, your sum for any partition is just $2f(x_*)$ for $x_{i+1}>x_*>x_i$. As the partition shrinks to zero, $x_*\to 0$ and $f$ is continuous.

Comment: Ok , was the partition that you considered $P$=$\{[-1,x_i],(x_i,x_{i+1}),[x_{i+1},1]\}$

Comment: It is whatever partition you like, the important thing is that the mesh size goes to 0. You really don't have to think about any other points in the partition other than these two

Comment: certainly, good luck