# Prove a function is Riemann-Stieltjes integrable, and the fomula of its integral, in exercise 11.8.5 of Analysis I of Tao

Tags: real-analysis

$\newcommand{\sgn}{\operatorname{sgn}}$Let $\sgn:\mathbb R \rightarrow\mathbb R$ be the signum function

$$\left\{ \begin{array}{rcl}
         1& \mbox{when}
         & x>0 \\ 0  & \text{when} & x=0 \\
         -1 & \text{for} & x<0
                \end{array}\right.$$

let $f:[-1,1] \rightarrow\mathbb R$ be a countinuous function. Show that  $f$ is Riemann Stieltjes integrable with respect to sgn, and that

$$\int_{[-1,1]}f \, d\sgn = 2f(0).$$

Hint: find for every $\varepsilon>0$ a piecewise continuous function majorizing and minorizing $f$ whose Riemann-Stieltjes integral is $\varepsilon$-close to $2f(0).$

---

There is an answer in here, [Showing that f is Riemann integrable](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2626855/showing-that-f-is-riemann-integrable), but to me it isn't a proper answer, because the the respondent introduced additional concepts, which are not provided yet in the text. How to prove following the approach in the textbook Analysis I of Tao?

Comment: The only mention in that answer of anything that you would not have learned yet is the bit about "$f(0)$ is finite because $f$ is continuous in a compact domain". However, that part was completely unnecessary. We are given that $f : [-1, 1] \to \Bbb R$. That implies $f(0) \in \Bbb R$, and is therefore automatically finite. qbert was thinking about a more general version of the problem, and added a comment that was unnecessary for the specific problem here. Everything else mentioned comes straight from the definition of the R-S integral, and definition of continuity.